# NodeJS: You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected

Tags: node.js, warnings

I am using nodejs v10.19.0
I don't think I had any conflict so far but is this something I should worry about? I am getting this warning message in the console:

```
You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected
```

When I try to `npm install -g npm` I get these errors:

```
(node:9105) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/olivier/.npm/_logs/2020-07-06T08_55_45_873Z-debug.log
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated npm with `npm install -g npm`?

Comment: I just did but, got plenty of error messages :(

Comment: Post your errors

Comment: OK, but I will add them to my original post, because it's too long for here.

Answer (score 1):

The EACCESS error usually occurs when you try to install a package in a local you have no access to. Try to update npm with sudo before the command npm install.

Comment: Thanks that work for the ```sudo npm install -g npm```
But I still get ```npm WARN You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected```